# AWK--Print From End of Line till string is found

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Using awk or sed, how would one print from the end of a line until (the first instance of) a string was found. For instance, if `flow` were the string then `flow.com` would be parsed from `www.stackoverflow.com` and similarly for `www.flow.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line if it works for you:

```
awk -F'flow' 'NF>1{print FS$NF}' file
```

alternative one-liner:

```
awk 'sub(/.*flow/,"flow")' file
```

test (I added some numbers to the EOL, so that we know where did the output come from):

```
kent$  cat f
www.stackoverflow.com1
and similarly for 2 
www.flow.stackoverflow.com3

kent$  awk -F'flow' 'NF>1{print FS$NF}' f
flow.com1
flow.com3

kent$  awk 'sub(/.*flow/,"flow")' f
flow.com1
flow.com3
```

note that if the string has some speical meaning (for regex) chars, like `*, |, [ ...` you may need to escape those.

Comment: The last answer using sub was particularly helpful. Do you mind explaining the logic behind it?

Comment: @stat_novice awk's `sub(..)` return a number, how many times the substitution was done. if it is 0, means no "string" found in the line, we ignore it. otherwise, we chop from 1st char till the last occurrence of the string.

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line:

```
sed 's/.*\(flow\)/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep can do it:

```
grep -oP 'flow(?!.*flow).*' <<END
www.stackoverflow.com
nothing here
www.flow.stackoverflow.com
END
```

```
flow.com
flow.com
```

That regular expression finds "flow" where, looking ahead, "flow" is not found, and then the rest of the line.

This would also work: simpler regex but more effort:

```
rev filename | grep -oP '^.*?wolf' | rev
```